# Stuck in implementing a Bitmap

Tags: c, bitmap

I am trying to implement Set/Clear functions of a bitmap. However, I am stuck at a position where I have implemented the function but I Do not know how to pass the bitmap into the function.

```
int bitmap_set_bit(unsigned char * bitmap, int size, int target_pos)
{

   unsigned char var = *(bitmap + target_pos/8);
   var = ~(var & (0x01 << (target_pos%8)));

   *(bitmap + target_pos/8) = var;



   return 0;


}
```

So basically, from my main() if I call this function as below,

```
int main()
{
  unsigned char *Array = {255,255,254};

  bitmap_set_bit(&Array,10);

  printf("%i\n", Array);
}
```

The printf() statement in main prints 65535 always. I don't understand what to do.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: If you want debugging-help, provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What do you *expect* it to print? You're starting with a bitmap that has bit 10 set, so setting it wouldn't even do anything.

Comment: I have modified the code which should compile now

Comment: I want to print the changed value after set the bit.

Comment: I am basically creating a memory manager in which I intend to use the bitmap to determine which block of memory is free/allocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to completly understand exactly what your problem is, but this may help you.

(I have taken `size = 10` and `target_pos = 1` for calling the `bitmap_set_bit` function.)

In your main program you can use `Array` variable as below:

```
unsigned char Array[] = {255,255,254};
bitmap_set_bit(Array,10,1);
printf("%i\n", Array[0]);  
printf("%i\n", Array[1]);  
printf("%i\n", Array[2]);
```

or:

```
unsigned char * Array;
Array = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);
*Array = 255;
*(Array + 1) = 255;
*(Array + 2) = 254;
bitmap_set_bit(Array,10,1);
printf("%i\n", *Array);
printf("%i\n", *(Array+1));
printf("%i\n", *(Array+2));
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me understand better the concept.